# Using windowName in window.open()

Tags: javascript, html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
lists the `window.open()` method as having the syntax
`window.open(url, windowName, [windowFeatures]);`.

It says it is an optional parameter and 
"A DOMString specifying the name of the browsing context (window,  or tab) into which to load the specified resource; if the name doesn't indicate an existing context, a new window is created and is given the name specified by windowName."

However, whenever I try accessing a window's name, all I get is `""` for any other tab or window I open. I am using Opera now.

Comment: I would expect this behavior if the `url` is of a different origin than the window opener. Firefox does this. See [window.name can be used as an XSS attack vector](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=444222).